# What is the industry standard for reporting on an EAV database model?

Tags: sql, database, reporting, entity-attribute-value, cognos

Everywhere I look, I see explanations and deep dives showing why EAV is bad, and what we should be doing instead.

I have yet to find a post that actually shows a solution for the reporting side of an EAV database.

I've been asked to provide some basic reports, as well as slicing and dicing off of the various keys in the database. (Think user profile - how many live in this zipcode and like dogs).

I have Cognos 10 available, and the data is stored on a SQL 2005 box. How can I accomplish reporting this data in a reasonable fashion?

Comment: EAV is the exact opposite of what a good reporting schema is. You simply can't use it for reporting. Reporting requires denormalization while EAV is normalization carried to the extreme and then some. You ar really asking the wrong question here.

Comment: How should I be asking it? I have an existing database with EAV data that users have reporting requirements on. I'm looking for solutions to this...is there a way to transform the crap we have into data that we can report on?

Comment: The 'standard' solution is to first join to the EAV table a bunch of times to get the relevant columns into a more 'usual' format (normal records), potentially in CTEs or views, then doing reporting off of that.  Barring any vendor-specific constructs - need six 'column's worth of data from the EAV?  Join to it six times...

Comment: And for anything that reports on it, is it safe to assume there is no automatic detection when new attributes are created?